# Query on a recursive collection Laravel JensSegers mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, recursive-query

how can I find an object by value ?, json object can be recursive as the example

```
  [id] => f81f753b30bf
[title] => aa
[description] =>
[child] => Array (
     [0] => Array (
         [id] => 0485d8538197
         [title] => 11
         [description] =>
         [url] => -
         [child] => Array (
             [0] => Array (
                 [id] => 0485d4448197
                 [title] => 11
                 [description] =>
                 [url] => -
                 [child] => Array (
                 )
             )
         )
     )
     [1] => Array (
         [id] => 95e27b97831b
         [title] => 55
         [description] =>
         [url] => -
         [child] => Array (
         )
     )
),,
```

I need to recover a child object by id, thanks